# Is there a way to call Macro-Precision in Hugging Face Trainer?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I'm currently making tests on the DEFT-2015 dataset using Hugging Face models. I would like to compare my results to what has been done.

I checked in the `list_metrics` method from the `datasets` library, but I did not see Macro Precision, which was the metric used at the time by the researchers.

Do you have any indication for how I could tackle the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `huggingface` library (version `4.20.0`) seems to depend behind the curtains calls to scikit-learn library.

If you just use (without using `scikit-learn`):

```
from datasets import load_metric
metric = load_metric("precision")
precision = metric.compute(predictions=[...],references=[...])
```

it will throw an error that

> scikit-learn is not installed.

Why this intro?

Well, in fact, you can easily use datasets metrics to calculate however you want your metric (just exactly like scikit-learn does).

You just need to add the 'average' parameter:

```
  from datasets import load_metric
  metric = load_metric("precision")
  precision = metric.compute(predictions = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                             references  = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                             average='macro')
  # This prints 0.833333334
  print(precision)
```

The snippet above will print `{'precision': 0.8333333333333334}`, because `(1 + 1 + 0.5) / 3  = 0.83`, which is exactly the definition of macro precision you are searching for.

Conclusion : Use the `average` parameter to set the way you want to calculate your metric (micro/macro/weighted).